# I got this error , but I can't solve it. com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert an object of type java.lang.String to type, seem this error always happens but I still don't know how to solve it.

This is my activity to display RecyclerView:

```
    package com.example.budget

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Gravity
import android.view.View
import android.widget.ImageButton
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.budget.data.bill
import com.example.budget.login_register.LoginActivity
import com.google.firebase.database.*
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference


class TransactionActivity : AppCompatActivity(),NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    lateinit var drawer_layout: DrawerLayout
    lateinit var ref: DatabaseReference
    lateinit var database: FirebaseDatabase
    lateinit var nav_view: NavigationView
    lateinit var btnMenu: ImageButton
    var isbtnMenuClicked: Boolean = false
    var id: Int = 0
    var strName =""
    var strEmail = ""
    lateinit var nav_header : View
    lateinit var tvName: TextView
    lateinit var tvEmail: TextView
    lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    lateinit var list_bill : ArrayList<bill>
    lateinit var billRecycleView : RecyclerView
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_transaction)

    billRecycleView = findViewById(R.id.list_bill)
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    drawer_layout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
    nav_view = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
    btnMenu = findViewById(R.id.btnMenu)
    nav_header = nav_view.getHeaderView(0)
    tvName = nav_header.findViewById(R.id.tvName)
    tvEmail = nav_header.findViewById(R.id.tvEmail)
    setUsername()
    setEmail()

    nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
    btnMenuClicked()
    auth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    billRecycleView.layoutManager= LinearLayoutManager(this)
    billRecycleView.setHasFixedSize(true)
    list_bill = arrayListOf<bill>()
    getTransaction()


}

fun getTransaction(){
    val uid = auth.currentUser!!.uid
    ref = database.getReference("Bill").child(uid)
    ref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()){
                for (data in snapshot.children){
                    val model = data.getValue(bill::class.java)
                    list_bill.add(model!!)
                }
                billRecycleView.adapter = Myadpater(list_bill)
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

    })
}
```

This is Myadapter class

```
class Myadpater(val list_bill: ArrayList<bill>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<Myadpater.MyViewHolder>() {
    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val category: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TCategory)
        val expense: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TExpense)
        val date :TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TDate)

    }
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
    val itemView =
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.transaction_history, parent, false)
    return MyViewHolder(itemView)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.category.text = list_bill[position].category
    holder.expense.text = list_bill[position].expense
    holder.date.text = list_bill[position].date
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return list_bill.size
}
```

}

```
  class Myadpater(val list_bill: ArrayList<bill>) :
       RecyclerView.Adapter<Myadpater.MyViewHolder>() {
       class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
         val category: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TCategory)
         val expense: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TExpense)
         val date :TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TDate)

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val itemView =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.transaction_history, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.category.text = list_bill[position].category
        holder.expense.text = list_bill[position].expense
        holder.date.text = list_bill[position].date
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list_bill.size
    }

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkWoS.png)

this is the error that I get

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.budget, PID: 5201
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.budget.data.bill
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(CustomClassMapper.java:436)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(CustomClassMapper.java:232)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(CustomClassMapper.java:80)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:203)
    at com.example.budget.TransactionActivity$getTransaction$1.onDataChange(TransactionActivity.kt:71)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using the following reference:

```
ref = database.getReference("Bill").child(uid)
```

And looping through the DataSnapshot using the following loop:

```
for (data in snapshot.children){
    val model = data.getValue(bill::class.java)
    list_bill.add(model!!)
}
```

It means that you are trying to get each child that exists within the UID node and convert it to an object of type `model`. Seeing your screenshot, I can say that there are no `model` objects under the UID node, but only String objects. Since there is no way in Kotlin in which you can convert a String to an object of type `model`, you get the mentioned error. If you want to have multiple `model` objects under the UID node, then you should use [push()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#push()), every time you add data:

```
ref.push().setValue(yourModelObj).addOnCompleteListener(/* ... /*)
//  ^^^^^
```

Your new database schema will look like this:

```
Firebase-root
  |
  --- Bill
       |
       --- KoqT...O6H3
             |
             --- $pushedId //Newly added level
                    |
                    --- categoryy: "food"
                    |
                    --- date: "22 Jul, 2021"
                    |
                    --- expense: "20"
```

To get all `model` objects back, there is nothing to do, your actual code will work perfectly fine.

P.S. Don't forget to remove the String values that exist right now, otherwise, you'll continue to get that Exception.

Comment: Thanks!!! MAN, You helped a lot. It works perfectly now.

Comment: Good to hear that, @kianhun4167chai